# Could not initialize class $line10.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$

Tags: scala

I am starting my day with a weird problem. Really can't see what is wrong with my code. Take the lines below

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f2 = Future.failed(new Exception("I do nothing"))
def f1 = Future { println("working"); Thread.sleep(5000); 1 }

val list = List(f2, f1)
val consolidated = Future.sequence(list)
consolidated.onComplete {
  case Success(_) => println("completed successfully")
  case Failure(e) => println(s"failed with ${e.getMessage}")
}
Await.result(consolidated, Duration.Inf)
```

and do a `:paste` in the REPL. I see a weird exception

```
~ > scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f2 = Future.failed(new Exception("no work"))
def f1 = Future { println("working"); Thread.sleep(5000); 1 }

val list = List(f2, f1)
val consolidated = Future.sequence(list)
consolidated.onComplete {
  case Success(_) => println("completed successfully")
  case Failure(e) => println(s"failed with ${e.getMessage}")
}
Await.result(consolidated, Duration.Inf)


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcI$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcI$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:653)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:251)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:287)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
java.lang.Exception: I do nothing
  at .f2(<console>:16)
  ... 29 elided

scala>
```

I really see no reason for `Could not initialize class` errors. According to me the code should just print "failed with no work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this

```
Await.result(consolidated, Duration.Inf)
```

when you `Await` a `Future`, and that future fails, the exception it contains is thrown. Due to how the REPL works, having an uncaught exception causes some of its machinery to break. This seems like a bug in the REPL, but it doesn't seem to have been reported yet.

Note than `onComplete` doesn't change the result of a `Future`. It simply schedules something to be done after the `Future` is complete. In particular, it does not consume the `Future`. If you meant to transform the `Future`, you would do something like this:

```
val transformed: Future[String] = consolidated.andThen {
  case Success(v) => "Completed successfully"
  case Failure(e) => s"Failed with ${e.getMessage}"
}

println(Await.result(transformed, Duration.Inf))
```