# Scala futures and Await.result()

Tags: scala, future

I expect the following code to result in `syncResult` containing "string two", but instead, I get the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class`.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def randomFunction1(): Future[String] = {
    Future.successful("string one")
}

def randomFunction2(): Future[String] = {
    Future.successful("string two")
}

val asyncResult: Future[String] = for {
    r1 <- randomFunction1()
    r2 <- randomFunction2()
} yield r2

val syncResult: String = Await.result(
    asyncResult,
    1.second
)
```

I get similar results with the following.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def randomFunction1(): Future[String] = {
    Future.successful("string one")
}

def randomFunction2(): Future[String] = {
    Future.successful("string two")
}

val asyncResult: Future[String] = randomFunction1().flatMap(
    r1 => {
        randomFunction2()
    }
)

val syncResult: String = Await.result(
    asyncResult,
    1.second
)
```

I'm using the Scala 2.12.2 interpreter to run this using `:paste`.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your `Await()` is timing out due to the REPL environment. It runs without error when compiled from a file or from within an IntelliJ worksheet.

Comment: @jwvh for me both examples work as expected in REPL. 
David could you post the complete exception, i.e. with call stack?

Comment: If you replace the `Await.result` block with `asyncResult onComplete {
  case Success(a) => print(a)
  case Failure(err) => print("failed")
}` then it should work.  Seems like a problem with `Await.result`

Comment: I think this is the same underlying problem as https://stackoverflow.com/q/45839567/5684257. The timeout is exceeded (for some mundane reason, likely the REPL baggage just slowing things down), causing `Await.result` to throw an exception in some dark-magic manner that breaks some other bit of REPL machinery. EDIT: Yep, the `NoClassDefFoundError` is caused by the `TimeoutException` thrown in `<clinit>`.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to be an issue with the Scala REPL.